# Is it necessary to check null after GetResponseAsync?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I had seen many times people posting httpwebrequest code including a line to check if GetResponseAsync return null. In my experience, I never ran into a situation with a null response. It either throws an webexception or return a valid response

Although the line makes no difference in term of performance, I do want to remove unnecessary code. Please tell me a direction to check.

```
public async void Request()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
    req.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync();
    if ( res == null ) return; // Is this line necessary?
}
```

Comment: The null check I think is superfluous in the code you have posted, even if there were a case where the response would return null, it would throw on the line before the null check as you can't cast null.

Comment: Thank you. Would appreciate if anyone could point out a method to check if there is a case it will return null so I know how to deal with this kind of problem myself